# how to store data in firebase android

Tags: android, firebase

I am new with android and I implemented function which generate QR code and store data in database using firebase realtime database its generate the QR code but it is doesn't store the data and stop the program by the way I am using android studio

```
private void addItem(){
        String name=text.getText().toString().trim();
        String price=textPrice.getText().toString().trim();
        String expire=textExpire.getText().toString().trim();
        if((!TextUtils.isEmpty(name)) &&(! TextUtils.isEmpty(price))&&(! TextUtils.isEmpty(expire))){
            String id=databaseItem.push().getKey();
            Items item=new Items(id,name,price,expire,bitmap);
            databaseItem.child(id).setValue(item);

        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(this,"You should fill all fields",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
}
```

this is the track trace

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.androidexample.myqueueskip, PID: 30710
    com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Serializing Arrays is not supported, please use Lists instead
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:160)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.access$200(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:47)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:663)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:167)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.access$200(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:47)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:663)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:167)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.access$200(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:47)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:663)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:167)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertToPlainJavaTypes(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:60)
        at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.setValueInternal(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:292)
        at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.setValue(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:166)
        at com.androidexample.myqueueskip.MainActivity.addItem(MainActivity.java:70)
        at com.androidexample.myqueueskip.MainActivity.access$000(MainActivity.java:22)
        at com.androidexample.myqueueskip.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:53)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6294)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24770)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Comment: I didn't get any error but the run is stopped at the emulator and didn't save the information.

Comment: show us the code for the class `Items` if you have a field which is an Array, change it to a List.

Comment: Looks like you are trying to store QR Code Bitmap inside the Firestore Which is not supported. To store bitmap image use **FirebaseStorage**.

Comment: can i store information like name and price in Firebase storage?

Comment: you can store name and price but can not store bitmap. Either convert it into base64 String.